# Menu container width is smaller then the content

Tags: css, containers, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic-UI in project. When resize a window, the width of the menu container becomes smaller then the menu items width.

[image]

You can see this effect on the [Semantic-UI example page](https://semantic-ui.com/examples/theming.html)

Sample code.

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.big.block {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sixteen column">
      <div class="ui floated left main mini menu">
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          some item
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="big block">big block</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example in the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv3czdeq/2/)

How to fix this?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: What's your expected behaviour? You would either need to make the wrapper overflow: auto so a scrollbar is introduced when the menu is wider than the available space, or have the items within the menu reflow onto 2+ lines I guess.

Comment: @delinear, the scrollbar already appear on the page. But the menu container still has the same behavior. See my example, which I just added.